# Get the month click of DateTimePicker in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

How do i check the month arrow click event of DateTimePicker. when i'm trying to change the month of datetimepicker then it is giving the 1st date of that next month so I've to prevent that month click.

Please see the image:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing the usage of CloseUp And DropDown events and Binding data may be the solution

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    Public Partial Class Form1
        Inherits Form
        Private isDropedDown As Boolean
        Private m_dataSale As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Public Property DataSale() As DateTime
            Get
                Return m_dataSale
            End Get
            Set
                If isDropedDown Then
                    If m_dataSale.[Date].AddMonths(1).[Date] = value.[Date] OrElse m_dataSale.[Date].AddMonths(-1).[Date] = value.[Date] OrElse New DateTime(m_dataSale.Year, m_dataSale.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).[Date] = value.[Date] OrElse New DateTime(m_dataSale.Year, m_dataSale.Month, 1).AddMonths(-1).[Date] = value.[Date] Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Month is changing")
                    End If
                End If

                m_dataSale = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            Dim binding = dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value", Me, "DataSale")
            binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
        End Sub
        Private Sub dateTimePicker1_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            isDropedDown = False
        End Sub

        Private Sub dateTimePicker1_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            isDropedDown = True
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Hi, now I'm handling the ValueChanged event of Datetimepicker, but it is calling at both time (i.e. when we click on specific date and when on month arrow click)so my question is that how do i recognize the month arrow click on datetimepicker because at both time value change is called.

Comment: @Rahul Shirphule i have changed the answer pal